# Can I see from here if this integral is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, even-and-odd-functions

I'm computing the following integral:

> $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(\rho)\sin(\theta)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho)\sin(\theta)~d\theta d\rho$$

Till this point I did everything correct, since when I compute it with a calculator it gets $0$ which is also the right solution. But is there a way to say now that it gets zero? Because I can't see how to procede and maybe one can argue with odd functions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the $\sin(\theta)$ integral over a full period should already evaluate to $0$, unless I'm overlooking something

Answer (score 6):

Write the integral as
$$\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^2(\rho)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho)\,d\rho\right)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta.$$
Since $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta=0$ (show this directly or by symmetry about $\pi$), the entire expression is zero.

Comment: sorry why can I write it as a multiplication?

Comment: Because no part of the $\theta$ integral (including bounds) depends on $\rho$ and vice versa, the $\theta$ integral can be factored out of the $\rho$ integral.

Comment: is this then really a multiplication?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly two integrals multiplied together.

Comment: Fubini's theorem allows you to iterate integrals as shown in this answer.

Comment: @AlexS is it just like $\int 3x~dx=3\int x~dx$? but with more variables and instead of real numbers with functions

Comment: Yes, but as @DonAntonio mentioned, you need Fubini's Theorem to see that it is fine (in cases like this one) to factor out an integral as well.

Comment: @AlexS but we had in fubini only that we can swap integrals, we have never seen this conclusion

Comment: This is getting a little too involved for comments, I suggest you ask a new question. I believe I can answer it.

Comment: okey I will do it.

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 2):

The function is odd with respect to the line $\theta = \pi$, so the integral is zero.

Comment: How can one see this directly?

Comment: Set $f(\rho, \theta) = \sin^2 \rho \cdot (\sin \theta -\cos \rho \sin \theta)$ and check that $f(\rho, \theta) = -f(\rho, 2\pi -\theta), \quad \theta \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: yes sure but if I don't know that it is $\pi$ then I don't know in which intervall $\theta$ should live

Comment: The symmetries that allow this kind of immediate simplifications are the one the coincide with natural symmetries in the integration region, so $\theta = \pi$ is a natural choice.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your answer, could you explain it maybe a bit more? I'm sorry

Comment: Take for instance $\int_{-1}^1 \sin t dt$. You conclude that the integral is zero because $\sin t$ is an odd function in the interval $[-1,1]$. If the interval was $[-2,1]$ you could not take the same conclusion, it was important that the interval itself had some symmetry. The same happens in 2D, we search for lines of symmetry in the domain and,  if the function to be integrated is symmetric with respect to one of those lines, the integral is zero.

Comment: aha and how can I find such a line without drawing it? because this seems to need a lot of experience