# How can I see that I can rewrite this integral with a multiplication.

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the folllwoing integral

> $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(\rho)\sin(\theta)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho)\sin(\theta)~d\theta d\rho$$
> and I would like to know why exaclty one can rewrite it as follows
> $$\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^2(\rho)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho)\,d\rho\right)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta.$$

Thanks for your help

Comment: In practice, you first factor out $\sin \theta$ then you can pull out from the integral in $d\theta$ everything that does not contain $\theta$. If you are asking about the theory, it is Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Isn't the same question you asked a while earlier? You could have sought clarifications to the answer to your original question rather than asking a new question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373096/can-i-see-from-here-if-this-integral-is-zero

Comment: @MathLover Yes it is, but AlexS asked me to do a new one since he doesn't want do discuss it in the comments.

Comment: I wonder why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, factor out the $\sin\theta$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin^2(\rho)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho))\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\rho.$$
Since $\rho$ does not depend on $\theta$, it can be factored out of the inner $\theta$ integral (just as a constant can be factored out of an integral):
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}(\sin^2(\rho)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho))\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\rho.$$
The quantity $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta$ is just a number (in this case, it is zero), so it can be factored out of the outer $\rho$ integral just as any number can:$$\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}(\sin^2(\rho)-\cos(\rho)\sin^2(\rho))\,d\rho\right)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta.$$

In general, the following holds via the same logic:
$$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x)g(y)\,dy\,dx=\left(\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_c^d g(y)\,dy\right).$$

Comment: ah perfect thanks!